# Is there a convention for breaking chemical formulae across lines?

Tags: notation

I found a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=36063845#36063845) where a user asked for chemical formulae to be broken across lines (with LaTeX/mhchem). I could imagine offering a switch to allow this. But only, if line-breaking within formulae is not completely uncommon.

According to him/her, possible breaking points in $\ce{[nBu4N]2[(UO2)2(\mu-\eta^2:\eta^2-O2)(NO3)2(\mu-Au(CN)2)2]}$ would be
$\ce{[nBu4N]2~\color{red}{|}~[(UO2)2~\color{red}{|}~(\mu-\eta^2:\eta^2-O2)~\color{red}{|}~(NO3)2~\color{red}{|}~(\mu-Au(CN)2)2]}$.
So a rule could be "allow a line-break before `(`, `[` or `\{` (which would introduce another possible breakpoint into the example).

Is it common to break long formulae across lines and is doing so sensible?

Comment: I think, chemical formulae should not be broken across lines. I can’t remember seeing it happen in large scales anywhere — but it could happen in journals due to their thin column layouts. I’ll try and keep an eye out.

Comment: What if the formula is too long to fit on one line?  That looks like the real q.

Answer (score 6):

I remember a couple of books from 1970-80s, where long formulas were split with what would be a $\rm \LaTeX$ `\cdot` "$\cdot$" notation, I believe. This is an example from Pope, M. T.; Jeannin, Y.; Fournier, M. "Heteropoly and isopoly oxometalates" in *Inorganic Chemistry Concepts*; Springer: Berlin, **1983**; Vol. 8.:

[image]

The reason for that, it seems, is that the book was printed in A5 format. Personally, I find an option for `mhchem` to be able to split formulas across pages very useful.